# KeyError exception using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get a `KeyError: ('user rating score', 'occurred at index title')` traceback when I try to execute the code below. I tried changing the axis after the `remove_na_scores` in my `apply()` function, however nothing is working.

```
import pandas as pd
import pprint

shows = pd.read_csv('/Users/WilliamStevens/Downloads/netflix_shows.csv')
pprint.pprint(shows.head())
shows.info()

shows_df = shows.groupby(['ratingDescription']).mean()
print(shows_df)

missing_user_scores = shows[shows['user rating score'].isnull()]
mean_scores = shows.groupby(['ratingDescription'])['user rating score'].mean()

def remove_na_scores(row):
    if pd.isnull(row['user rating score']):
        return mean_scores[row['rating']]
    else:
        return row['user rating score']

shows['user rating score'] = shows.apply(remove_na_scores)

print(shows['user rating score'])
```

The full traceback is follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "netflix.py", line 28, in <module>
shows['user rating score'] = shows.apply(remove_na_scores)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4163, in apply
return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4259, in _apply_standard
results[i] = func(v)
    File "netflix.py", line 23, in remove_na_scores
if pd.isnull(row['user rating score']):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2169, in get_value
tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
    File "pandas/index.pyx", line 105, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3567)
    File "pandas/index.pyx", line 113, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3250)
    File "pandas/index.pyx", line 163, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4373)
KeyError: ('user rating score', 'occurred at index title')
```

Comment: please show the entire traceback, that way we know where the error occurred.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netflix.py", line 28, in <module>
    shows['user rating score'] = shows.apply(remove_na_scores)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4163, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4259, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "netflix.py", line 23, in remove_na_scores
    if pd.isnull(row['user rating score']):

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2169, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 105, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3567)

Comment: File "pandas/index.pyx", line 113, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3250)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 163, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4373)
KeyError: ('user rating score', 'occurred at index title')

Comment: sorry - had to do it in 3 parts because was over the character limit

Comment: Please edit the question and put it there as a code block.  it is basically unreadable in the comments, thanks.

Comment: just added at the bottom inside the question

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
if pd.isnull(row['user rating score']):
```

Is where the error occurs.

It occurs because `remove_na_scores` is being applied along the wrong axis. Adding `, axis=1` to `shows.apply` should resolve the issue for which you posted the trace:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,2), columns = ['title', 'user rating score'])
>>>df.apply(lambda x: x['user rating score'])
...
KeyError: ('user rating score', 'occurred at index title')

>>>df.apply(lambda x: x['user rating score'], axis=1)
0    0.083195
1    0.243666
2    0.572457
3    0.885327
dtype: float64
```

Since you mention specifying the axis not working, I imagine you're getting another error following that. I can edit my post if you describe the new issue, but this should address the one described.